# How do I draw recursive Sierpiński arrowhead curve using python turtle graphics on Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Hi I am trying to draw a recursive Sierpiński arrowhead curve using turtle graphics in python on Visual Studio Code. I can get the basic shape just fine but I can't seem to make it rotate correctly to form the sierpinski triangle. Here's my code:

```
from turtle import * 
def arrowhead(level, length):
    if level == 1:
       rt(-60)
       fd(length)
       rt(60)
       fd(length)
       rt(60) #Basic shape for level 1 
    else:
       arrowhead(level-1, length/2)
       rt(60)
       for i in range(3):
           arrowhead(level-1, length/2)
           lt(-60)
       for i in range(3):
           arrowhead(level-1, length/2)
           rt(-60)
       arrowhead(level-1, length/2)
       lt(60)
       arrowhead(level-1, length/2)

arrowhead(4, 400)
```

Comment: what is this to do with VSC? It's a python only problem. SO is not for debugging by others. What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import turtle 

def seg(level, step, angle):
    if level>0:
        seg(level-1, step/2, -angle)
        T.rt(angle)
        seg(level-1, step/2,  angle)
        T.rt(angle)
        seg(level-1, step/2, -angle)
    else:
        T.fd(step)


# Main Code
turtle.bye()
T = turtle.Turtle()   
T.speed(10)
d = 220
b = 300
for level in range(7):
    T.penup()
    T.setpos((d*int(level/3)-b, d*(level%3)-b)) # pick new starting point
    T.setheading(0)                         # reset heading
    T.pendown()
    if level%2==1: # is level odd or even? if even than ...
        T.lt(60)
    seg(level, 200, 60)
```

and got [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlQBd.png)